High CPU usage of nearbyd, sharingd and bluetoothd
On an Intel Macbook Pro running macOS 14.5, after a while nearbyd, sharingd and bluetoothd start taking 10-20% CPU each permanently. I just can't figure out why, but some things I find quite weird. High CPU usage stops when:

The "Bluetooth" page in the System Settings are opened and in focus. As soon as it loses focus or is closed, CPU usage goes up again.
I disable Bluetooth in the System settings. Turning it back on makes CPU usage rise instantly.
I sign out of my Apple account. I sign back in, the problem resurfaces.

Console output did not show anything meaningful. I also unpaired all Bluetooth devices. At first I had macOS widgets (some of them paired from my iPhone) under suspicion, but even after removing all and rebooting, the problem comes back eventually. It also does not seem to appear right after a reboot, but when the system wakes up from sleep.
I'd appreciate any ideas as to what the cause could be or how to get any closer to it. Thanks much!
